# Use text data as mark labels in pgfplots

Tags: tables, pgfplots, labels

I have a table with numerical data and text in different columns, like this:

```
0   0   0.1
1   0   \pi
2   0   \frac{\pi}{2}
```

I'd like to put text labels on a plot using the text in the third column at the position given by the first two columns (I need to overlay these text labels on a plot at given positions). Is it possible with `pgfplots`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, that is possible. You'll need to tell `pgfplots` to expect symbolic meta data (so it doesn't try to parse it as numbers), which you do using the key `point meta=explicit symbolic`.

Since you're using math commands in your labels, you'll have to make sure they are typeset in math mode. You can do this using `nodes near coords=$\pgfplotspointmeta$`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
0   0   0.1
1   0   \pi
2   0   \frac{\pi}{2}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    nodes near coords=$\pgfplotspointmeta$,
    point meta=explicit symbolic
]
\addplot table [meta index=2] {data.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```