# Generate a discretized sine wave where the points are equally spaced apart w.r.t. the arclength of the curve

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to use tikz to discretize a sinusoidal wave like A(x)sin(bx) such that the line segments connecting the discretized points have a uniform length. Is there an easy way to do this? The only solution I can think of is using Matlab to find out the appropriate points and then tediously copy and pasting in the values into my tex editor (see code below).

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\label{fig:midline_discretization}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}(120, 50)
    \put(10.0000,25.0000){\circle*{2}}
    \put(20.9912,26.6953){\circle*{2}}
    \put(31.9241,24.9382){\circle*{2}}
    \put(42.0139,20.2444){\circle*{2}}
    \put(52.1888,15.7636){\circle*{2}}
    \put(63.1267,16.0286){\circle*{2}}
    \put(72.3473,22.1508){\circle*{2}}
    \put(80.0280,30.2114){\circle*{2}}
    \put(87.6501,38.3286){\circle*{2}}
    \put(97.0000,44.1400){\circle*{2}}  
    \draw (10.0000,25.0000) -- (20.9912,26.6953) -- (31.9241,24.9382) -- (42.0139,20.2444) -- (52.1888,15.7636) -- (63.1267,16.0286) -- (72.3473,22.1508) -- (80.0280,30.2114) -- (87.6501,38.3286) -- (97.0000,44.1400) ;
    \put(2.5000,29.0000){$\mathbf X_{(0,m_2,m_3)}$}
    \put(14.9912,32.6953){$\mathbf X_{(1,m_2,m_3)}$}
    \put(28.9241,27.0382){$\mathbf X_{(2,m_2,m_3)}$}
    \put(92.0000,47.6400){$\mathbf X_{(N-1,m_2,m_3)}$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Clarification: Are you looking to control the line segment length, or the arc length? For the former, you can create the sinusoidal path and then, at each point, intersect the sinusoidal path with a small invisible circle (radius=length of line segment) to get the next point. For the latter, I recommend using Asymptote instead of TikZ, since Asymptote has an arclength function. (Metapost might also work, but I'm less familiar with it.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you ask for is actually highly non-trivial: Given some point $x$, the next point $x'$ would have to satisfy $(A(x')sin(x') - A(x)sin(x))^2 + (x'-x)^2 = d^2$.  There are better programs than Tikz to solve such an equation.

However, if you use pgfplots (which is based on tikz), you can transfer some of the work to TeX (or so), for example:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{filecontents*}{points.data}
   x        y
10.0000  25.0000
20.9912  26.6953

31.9241  24.9382
42.0139  20.2444

52.1888  15.7636
63.1267  16.0286

72.3473  22.1508
80.0280  30.2114

87.6501  38.3286
97.0000  44.1400
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}    
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[nodes near coords={$\mathbf{X}_{(\coordindex,m_{2},m_{3})}$},
    width=\textwidth]
    \addplot[mark=*] table {points.data};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

The trick here is to insert an empty line into the data file whenever you want to interrupt the line.

You can also specify the labels in the file ([Use text data as mark labels in pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53545/use-text-data-as-mark-labels-in-pgfplots)), which can be used to suppress some of the labels (apparently, when the label is missing in some row, the last label is repeated, thus the {} in the fourth data row):

```
\begin{filecontents*}{points.data}
   x        y      label
10.0000  25.0000  \mathbf{X}_{(0,m_{2},m_{3})}
20.9912  26.6953  \mathbf{X}_{(1,m_{2},m_{3})}

31.9241  24.9382  \mathbf{X}_{(2,m_{2},m_{3})}
42.0139  20.2444  {}

52.1888  15.7636  
63.1267  16.0286  

72.3473  22.1508  
80.0280  30.2114  

87.6501  38.3286  
97.0000  44.1400  \mathbf{X}_{(N-1,m_{2},m_{3})}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[nodes near coords={$\pgfplotspointmeta$},
    point meta=explicit symbolic,
    width=\textwidth]
    \addplot[mark=*] table [meta index=2] {points.data};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Finally, you can also tell pgfplots to compute the function for you, so it suffices to give the x values:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{points.data}
   x
10.0000
20.9912

31.9241
42.0139

52.1888
63.1267

72.3473
80.0280

87.6501
97.0000
\end{filecontents*}

\tikzset{declare function={f(\x)=\x^3*sin(4.5*\x)/10^5+4;}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[nodes near coords={$\mathbf{X}_{(\coordindex,m_{2},m_{3})}$},
    width=\textwidth]
    \addplot[mark=*] table [y expr=f(\thisrowno{0})] {points.data};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Pictures for all three codes:
[image: pictures for all three codes]

Comment: Great answer! And [welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Answer (score 2):

Another construction with markings decoration and using sequence numbers which is further fiddlable.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[dashed sine/.style={postaction={decorate},
  decoration={markings,mark=between positions 0 and 1 step {pi/6}*1cm with {%
    \edef\temp{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}}%
    \coordinate (mark-\temp);%
    \ifodd\temp\relax\else\draw (mark-\temp) -- (mark-\number\numexpr\temp-1\relax);\fi%
  }}}]
\draw[very thin,color=gray] (-0.1,-1.1) grid (5.9,1.9);
\path[draw=blue,dashed sine] plot[samples=151,domain=0:4] (\x,{sin(3*\x r)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The only issue is that I need to be able to connect the linear segments. Maybe overlaying this plot with a shifted sine wave would let me do that.

Comment: @namu How do you mean? The linear segments are already connected. And the end points are named already with `(mark-number)`

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[border=1]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
      \addplot[dash pattern=on 10pt off 10pt,samples=200,blue,thick]   {sin(deg(x))};
     \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Change `dash pattern=on 10pt off 10pt` as you like.

Comment: No, not quite. I need straight line segments connecting the discretized curve like in my sample code.